# SMTP emailing library

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

Some time ago, I implemented an emailing library to simplify sending emails for several web applications and daemons. As usual, I am interested in improving my code.

```py
"""Library for e-mailing."""

from __future__ import annotations
from configparser import ConfigParser, SectionProxy
from email.charset import Charset, QP
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.nonmultipart import MIMENonMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from functools import cache
from logging import getLogger
from smtplib import SMTPException, SMTP
from typing import Iterable, Optional
from warnings import warn


__all__ = ['EMail', 'Mailer']


LOGGER = getLogger('emaillib')


class MIMEQPText(MIMENonMultipart):
    """A quoted-printable encoded text."""

    def __init__(self, payload: str, subtype: str = 'plain',
                 charset: str = 'utf-8'):
        super().__init__('text', subtype, charset=charset)
        self.set_payload(payload, charset=get_qp_charset(charset))


class EMail(MIMEMultipart):
    """Email data for Mailer."""

    def __init__(self, subject: str, sender: str, recipient: str, *,
                 plain: str = None, html: str = None, charset: str = 'utf-8',
                 quoted_printable: bool = False):
        """Creates a new EMail."""
        super().__init__(subtype='alternative')
        self['Subject'] = subject
        self['From'] = sender
        self['To'] = recipient
        self['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True, usegmt=True)
        text_type = MIMEQPText if quoted_printable else MIMEText

        if plain is not None:
            self.attach(text_type(plain, 'plain', charset))

        if html is not None:
            self.attach(text_type(html, 'html', charset))

    def __str__(self):
        """Converts the EMail to a string."""
        return self.as_string()

    @property
    def subject(self):
        """Returns the Email's subject."""
        return self['Subject']

    @property
    def sender(self):
        """Returns the Email's sender."""
        return self['From']

    @property
    def recipient(self):
        """Returns the Email's recipient."""
        return self['To']


class Mailer:
    """A simple SMTP mailer."""

    def __init__(
            self,
            smtp_server: str,
            smtp_port: int,
            login_name: str,
            passwd: str,
            *,
            ssl: Optional[bool] = None,
            tls: Optional[bool] = None
    ):
        """Initializes the email with basic content."""
        self.smtp_server = smtp_server
        self.smtp_port = smtp_port
        self.login_name = login_name
        self._passwd = passwd

        if ssl is not None:
            warn('Option "ssl" is deprecated. Use "tls" instead.',
                 DeprecationWarning)

        self.ssl = ssl
        self.tls = tls

    def __call__(self, emails: Iterable[EMail]):
        """Alias to self.send()."""
        return self.send(emails)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.login_name}:*****@{self.smtp_server}:{self.smtp_port}'

    @classmethod
    def from_section(cls, section: SectionProxy) -> Mailer:
        """Returns a new mailer instance from the provided config section."""

        if (smtp_server := section.get(
                'smtp_server', section.get('host')
        )) is None:
            raise ValueError('No SMTP server specified.')

        if (port := section.getint(
                'smtp_port', section.getint('port')
        )) is None:
            raise ValueError('No SMTP port specified.')

        if (login_name := section.get(
                'login_name', section.get('user')
        )) is None:
            raise ValueError('No login nane specified.')

        if (passwd := section.get('passwd', section.get('password'))) is None:
            raise ValueError('No password specified.')

        return cls(
            smtp_server, port, login_name, passwd,
            ssl=section.getboolean('ssl'), tls=section.getboolean('tls')
        )

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config: ConfigParser) -> Mailer:
        """Returns a new mailer instance from the provided config."""
        return cls.from_section(config['email'])

    def _start_tls(self, smtp: SMTP) -> bool:
        """Start TLS connection."""
        try:
            smtp.starttls()
        except (SMTPException, RuntimeError, ValueError) as error:
            LOGGER.error('Error during STARTTLS: %s', error)

            # If TLS was explicitly requested, re-raise
            # the exception and fail.
            if self.ssl or self.tls:
                raise

            # If TLS was not explicitly requested, return False
            # to make the caller issue a warning.
            return False

        return True

    def _start_tls_if_requested(self, smtp: SMTP) -> bool:
        """Start a TLS connection if requested."""
        if self.ssl or self.tls or self.ssl is None or self.tls is None:
            return self._start_tls(smtp)

        return False

    def _login(self, smtp: SMTP) -> bool:
        """Attempt to log in at the server."""
        try:
            smtp.ehlo()
            smtp.login(self.login_name, self._passwd)
        except SMTPException as error:
            LOGGER.error(str(error))
            return False

        return True

    def send(self, emails: Iterable[EMail]) -> bool:
        """Sends emails."""
        with SMTP(host=self.smtp_server, port=self.smtp_port) as smtp:
            if not self._start_tls_if_requested(smtp):
                LOGGER.warning('Connecting without SSL/TLS encryption.')

            if not self._login(smtp):
                return False

            return send_emails(smtp, emails)


def send_email(smtp: SMTP, email: EMail) -> bool:
    """Sends an email via the given SMTP connection."""

    try:
        smtp.send_message(email)
    except SMTPException as error:
        LOGGER.warning('Could not send email: %s', email)
        LOGGER.error(str(error))
        return False

    return True


def send_emails(smtp: SMTP, emails: Iterable[EMail]) -> bool:
    """Sends emails via the given SMTP connection."""

    return all({send_email(smtp, email) for email in emails})


@cache
def get_qp_charset(charset: str) -> Charset:
    """Returns a quoted printable charset."""

    qp_charset = Charset(charset)
    qp_charset.body_encoding = QP
    return qp_charset
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noted the use of the `:=` operator aka **walrus**. That means your code requires Python >= 3.8 so consider adding a guard to make sure this requirement is satisfied.

Since you are aiming for recent versions of Python you could as well "upgrade" to a [data class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) that will make your code more concise. Thus you could declare your class `EMail` like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class EMail(MIMEMultipart):
    subject: str
    sender: str
    recipient: str
    plain: str
    html: str
    charset: str = 'utf-8'
    quoted_printable: bool = False
```

in lieu if an `__init__` method and you can use `self.variable` straight away without manual assignment.

One additional benefit is that a `__repr__()` method is already implemented for you.

The @property decorator can still be used casually:

```
@property
def subject(self) -> str:
    return self.subject
```

Then you may want to use [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) for additional initialization work eg:

```
def __post_init__(self):
    text_type = MIMEQPText if quoted_printable else MIMEText

    if plain is not None:
        self.attach(text_type(plain, 'plain', charset))

    if html is not None:
        self.attach(text_type(html, 'html', charset))
```

The downside of the data class is when you need **positional or named arguments**, so ask yourself if you need them or not.  See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55099243) for possible strategies plus [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.KW_ONLY) of the docs.

But note that the dataclass decorator has a `kw_only` argument:

> If true (the default value is False), then all fields will be marked
> as keyword-only

This is a matter of personal preference but this code:

```
def _login(self, smtp: SMTP) -> bool:
    """Attempt to log in at the server."""
    try:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.login(self.login_name, self._passwd)
    except SMTPException as error:
        LOGGER.error(str(error))
        return False

    return True
```

could be written as:

```
def _login(self, smtp: SMTP) -> bool:
    """Attempt to log in at the server."""
    try:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.login(self.login_name, self._passwd)
    except SMTPException as error:
        LOGGER.error(str(error))
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

(I'm always wary of indentation in Python)

Small typo on line 146:

```
raise ValueError('No login nane specified.')
```

SMTP login can be made optional as it's not always required, for example on a corporate LAN where local IP addresses are trusted (eg Postfix my_networks) or from some ISPs.

Comment: I finally went with the option to generate the `MIMEMultipart` object from the `EMail` dataclass: https://github.com/homeinfogmbh/emaillib/blob/master/emaillib.py#L47

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 (really already in 3.3, but made official in 3.6) to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Honestly, I don't see what your encapsulated `EMail` class offers above what the `EmailMessage` object already provides. In particular, Python now transparently decides whether or not something needs to be encoded as quoted-printable.

Here is a quick and dirty refactoring to use the modern policy-based `EmailMessage` API.

```
"""Library for e-mailing."""

from __future__ import annotations
from configparser import ConfigParser, SectionProxy
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import formatdate
from logging import getLogger
from smtplib import SMTPException, SMTP
from typing import Iterable, Optional
from warnings import warn


__all__ = ['EMail', 'Mailer']


LOGGER = getLogger('emaillib')


class EMail(EmailMessage):
    """Email data for Mailer."""

    def __init__(self, subject: str, sender: str, recipient: str, *,
                 plain: str = None, html: str = None):
        """Creates a new EMail."""
        super().__init__()
        self['Subject'] = subject
        self['From'] = sender
        self['To'] = recipient
        self['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True, usegmt=True)

        if plain is not None:
            self.set_content(plain, subtype='plain'))

        if html is not None:
            if plain is None:
                self.set_content(html, subtype='html')
            else:
                self.add_alternative(html, subtype='html')

    def __str__(self):
        """Converts the EMail to a string."""
        return self.as_string()

    @property
    def subject(self):
        """Returns the Email's subject."""
        return self['Subject']

    @property
    def sender(self):
        """Returns the Email's sender."""
        return self['From']

    @property
    def recipient(self):
        """Returns the Email's recipient."""
        return self['To']


class Mailer:
    """A simple SMTP mailer."""

    def __init__(
            self,
            smtp_server: str,
            smtp_port: int,
            login_name: str,
            passwd: str,
            *,
            ssl: Optional[bool] = None,
            tls: Optional[bool] = None
    ):
        """Initializes the email with basic content."""
        self.smtp_server = smtp_server
        self.smtp_port = smtp_port
        self.login_name = login_name
        self._passwd = passwd

        if ssl is not None:
            warn('Option "ssl" is deprecated. Use "tls" instead.',
                 DeprecationWarning)

        self.ssl = ssl
        self.tls = tls

    def __call__(self, emails: Iterable[EMail]):
        """Alias to self.send()."""
        return self.send(emails)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.login_name}:*****@{self.smtp_server}:{self.smtp_port}'

    @classmethod
    def from_section(cls, section: SectionProxy) -> Mailer:
        """Returns a new mailer instance from the provided config section."""

        if (smtp_server := section.get(
                'smtp_server', section.get('host')
        )) is None:
            raise ValueError('No SMTP server specified.')

        if (port := section.getint(
                'smtp_port', section.getint('port')
        )) is None:
            raise ValueError('No SMTP port specified.')

        if (login_name := section.get(
                'login_name', section.get('user')
        )) is None:
            raise ValueError('No login nane specified.')

        if (passwd := section.get('passwd', section.get('password'))) is None:
            raise ValueError('No password specified.')

        return cls(
            smtp_server, port, login_name, passwd,
            ssl=section.getboolean('ssl'), tls=section.getboolean('tls')
        )

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config: ConfigParser) -> Mailer:
        """Returns a new mailer instance from the provided config."""
        return cls.from_section(config['email'])

    def _start_tls(self, smtp: SMTP) -> bool:
        """Start TLS connection."""
        try:
            smtp.starttls()
        except (SMTPException, RuntimeError, ValueError) as error:
            LOGGER.error('Error during STARTTLS: %s', error)

            # If TLS was explicitly requested, re-raise
            # the exception and fail.
            if self.ssl or self.tls:
                raise

            # If TLS was not explicitly requested, return False
            # to make the caller issue a warning.
            return False

        return True

    def _start_tls_if_requested(self, smtp: SMTP) -> bool:
        """Start a TLS connection if requested."""
        if self.ssl or self.tls or self.ssl is None or self.tls is None:
            return self._start_tls(smtp)

        return False

    def _login(self, smtp: SMTP) -> bool:
        """Attempt to log in at the server."""
        try:
            smtp.ehlo()
            smtp.login(self.login_name, self._passwd)
        except SMTPException as error:
            LOGGER.error(str(error))
            return False

        return True

    def send(self, emails: Iterable[EMail]) -> bool:
        """Sends emails."""
        with SMTP(host=self.smtp_server, port=self.smtp_port) as smtp:
            if not self._start_tls_if_requested(smtp):
                LOGGER.warning('Connecting without SSL/TLS encryption.')

            if not self._login(smtp):
                return False

            return send_emails(smtp, emails)


def send_email(smtp: SMTP, email: EMail) -> bool:
    """Sends an email via the given SMTP connection."""

    try:
        smtp.send_message(email)
    except SMTPException as error:
        LOGGER.warning('Could not send email: %s', email)
        LOGGER.error(str(error))
        return False

    return True


def send_emails(smtp: SMTP, emails: Iterable[EMail]) -> bool:
    """Sends emails via the given SMTP connection."""

    return all({send_email(smtp, email) for email in emails})
```

You'll notice that `EMail` no longer accepts the `quoted_printable` parameter. I also removed `get_qp_charset` and the `MIMEQPText` class. Also, the `charset` keyword argument is gone. Exposing these internals and requiring knowledge about their significance was one of the problems of the old `compat32` API; this should now no longer be necessary.

I'm not particularly sold on the `@property` methods to return fields for which there is already a dictionary-like API, but I didn't remove them.

Your solution doesn't provide any support for `SMTP_SSL` servers. Whilst initially unencrypted port 587 with `STARTTLS` and password login after that is arguably best current practice for public SMTP submissions, there is still a sizable legacy of legacy port 465 servers which require TLS at handshake time.

I don't have a strong opinion about the `configparser` parts as such. If anything, I have a strong negative opinion about the `.ini` format itself; but if it works for you, more power to you.

Attempting to `starttls` even when this wasn't requested is odd. Shouldn't the attempt be made only if the user requested it? The current implementation basically makes it impossible to work without TLS if the server supports it. Pethaps that can be seen as a security feature, but then at the very least the code should log a warning if it activates TLS when the user might be trying to run without it.